# Prefix url Django

Tags: python, django, url, prefix

I am trying to make a customized prefix in urls for language without using i18n. The following code is in the root url file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^[a-z]{2}/', include('landing_page.urls')),
]
```

And the following code in landing_page.urls file;

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.LandingView, name='landing'),
]
```

Whenever I use;

```
<a href="{% url 'landing' %}"></a>
```

The following is displayed:

```
<a href="/aa/"></a>
```

How can I change "/aa/" automatically to the prefix for the current language (e.g. "/en/")? Without doing the following, since that gives many other problems in my setup.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<var>[a-z]{2})/', include('landing_page.urls')),
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I find this urlpattern quite strange, since it is not captured by a parameter at all...

Comment: The sole purpose of `i18n` is this. Why do you avoid using it?